# How to convert JSON columns to JSON rows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

How can I convert JSON columns to JSON rows?

From:

```json
[
  {
    "accountCode": "01",
    "accountName": "Cash on Hand",
    "HeadOffice": "100",
    "Marketing": "200",
    "Sales": "300",
    "Accounting": "400"
  },
  {
    "accountCode": "02",
    "accountName": "Cash in Bank",
    "HeadOffice": "150",
    "Marketing": "250",
    "Sales": "350",
    "Accounting": "450"
  },
  {
    "accountCode": "03",
    "accountName": "Loans",
    "HeadOffice": "250",
    "Marketing": "350",
    "Sales": "450",
    "Accounting": "450"
  },
  {
    "accountCode": "04",
    "accountName": "Advances",
    "HeadOffice": "150",
    "Marketing": "250",
    "Sales": "350",
    "Accounting": "450"
  }
]
```

To:

```json
[
  {
    "AccountCode": "01",
    "accountName": "Cash on Hand",
    "costCenter": "HeadOffice",
    "amount": "100"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "01",
    "accountName": "Cash on Hand",
    "costCenter": "Marketing",
    "amount": "200"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "01",
    "accountName": "Cash on Hand",
    "costCenter": "Sales",
    "amount": "300"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "01",
    "accountName": "Cash on Hand",
    "costCenter": "Accounting",
    "amount": "400"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "02",
    "accountName": "Cash in Bank",
    "costCenter": "HeadOffice",
    "amount": "150"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "02",
    "accountName": "Cash in Bank",
    "costCenter": "Marketing",
    "amount": "250"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "02",
    "accountName": "Cash in Bank",
    "costCenter": "Sales",
    "amount": "350"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "02",
    "accountName": "Cash in Bank",
    "costCenter": "Accounting",
    "amount": "450"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "03",
    "accountName": "Loans",
    "costCenter": "HeadOffice",
    "amount": "250"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "03",
    "accountName": "Loans",
    "costCenter": "Marketing",
    "amount": "350"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "03",
    "accountName": "Loans",
    "costCenter": "Sales",
    "amount": "450"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "03",
    "accountName": "Loans",
    "costCenter": "Accounting",
    "amount": "450"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "04",
    "accountName": "Advances",
    "costCenter": "HeadOffice",
    "amount": "150"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "04",
    "accountName": "Advances",
    "costCenter": "Marketing",
    "amount": "250"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "04",
    "accountName": "Advances",
    "costCenter": "Sales",
    "amount": "350"
  },
  {
    "AccountCode": "04",
    "accountName": "Advances",
    "costCenter": "Accounting",
    "amount": "450"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert JSON columns to JSON rows, you can iterate over the original JSON array, extract the desired fields, and create a new JSON array with the desired structure.

Example:

```
# Iterate over the original JSON data
for item in original_json:
    account_code = item["accountCode"]
    account_name = item["accountName"]
    
    # Iterate over the remaining key-value pairs in each object
    for key, value in item.items():
        if key not in ["accountCode", "accountName"]:
            result_json.append({
                "AccountCode": account_code,
                "accountName": account_name,
                "costCenter": key,
                "amount": value
            })

# Serialize the result array to JSON
result_json_str = json.dumps(result_json, indent=4)
print(result_json_str)
```